# Dimension of quotient construction

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

If I have an irreducible polynomial, $f$ with $deg(f) = n$ and I look at the quotient:

$$R = \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(f)}$$

How can we show that the dimension of $R$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space is equal to the degree of $f$? I guess this should be pretty standard, but I am struggling to understand it.

I want to show that we have a basis

$$1 + (f), x + (f), x^2 + (f), ..., x^{n-1} + (f)$$

Now I can show that this is spanning by using the division algorithm with elements of $R$, however how do we go about showing this is linearly independent?

Thanks

Comment: Irreducibility is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: what does it mean for $g \in R$ to be equal to 0? If $deg( g) < deg (f)$, can $g + (f) = 0$? Can you therefore show that $$\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}a_ix^i + (f) \ne 0\text{ }  \forall a_i \in \mathbb Q$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to prove that, if $f \in F[x]$ is irreducible, then $F[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle \cong F[\alpha]$.

To prove this, consider the evaluation homomorphism $ev_\alpha : F[x] \rightarrow F[\alpha]$ defined such that $g(x) \mapsto g(\alpha)$.  Of course, if you've never seen this before, you'll want to prove that this is indeed a homomorphism.  :)

Now apply the isomorphism theorem.

Comment: That seems a tad complicated for a problem like this. Especially because $f$ need not be irreducible

Comment: @Mathmo123, OP specified that $f$ is irreducible.  Even if it were reducible, then the problem is resolved by breaking it into a product of irreducible factors and ignoring the linear terms.  I.e. if $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, then $F[x]/f(x) = (F[x]/g(x))/h(x) \cong F[\alpha]/\langle h(x) \rangle \cong F[\alpha, \beta]$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $g$ and $\beta$ of $h$.  At least provided that $h(x)$ is still irreducible in $F[\alpha]$.  If not, one repeats the process.

Comment: Either way, this is some very heavy machinery for a problem that can be solved in one line following my hint.

Comment: @Mathmo123, I agree that it's pretty heavy.  Nevertheless, I think it's a good fact to prove because it comes in handy a quite a bit (for me at least).  Your method is certainly more direct.  Also, if the OP has never seen the isomorphism theorem, then your method is probably what's 'intended'.

Comment: It's certainly true that it comes in handy. It's an extremely powerful result. But for someone learning ring theory, it's important to be familiar with the basic stuff before one hits problems like this

Comment: @Mathmo123, you're right.  Ultimately, I hope that OP understands your way, and then will come back later on in his course and gain something from my response.

Comment: Both answers are very helpful, thank you!